# i have problem in subquery returns more than 1 row mysql error

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I'm getting error to execute subqueries. Below is my code and also attached image with error:-

```
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(`amount`) 
        FROM `test` 
    GROUP BY created_by
) + (
  SELECT SUM(`amount1`) 
        FROM `test1` 
    GROUP BY created_by
) AS `t`
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You group, but want to sum up all anyway? Doesn't make sense

Comment: Hi Mahesh. Welcome to stack overflow. Please post some sample table data and explain what you are trying to achieve from the query.

Comment: The subquery in select statement should not return more than one row. That is the primary reason for the error. In your case, you are grouping by 'created_by' column. So the subquery will return one row for every distinct 'created_by' and that is not supported in select subqueries. If you want your subquery to return multiple rows, you can try subqueries in join statement.

Comment: improved question